# ggplot2 labs left justification and data ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question on the plot created with ggplot2 package. Let's say we have such a plot:

```
df = data.frame(
  numbers = seq(1,5),
  labels = c(
    "Brand",
    "Good Brand",
    "The Best Brand",
    "The Best Brand Today",
    "The Best Brand This Month"
  )
)
df = df[order(-df$numbers),]
plot = ggplot(data = df, aes(x=labels, y=numbers))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill='orange')+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(
    title = "Exemplary title",
    caption = "Exemplary caption 1\nExemplary caption number 2"
  )+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = -0.5),
    panel.spacing = unit(c(0,0,0,20), "cm")
  )
plot
```

And my situation is as the following:

1. Making negative `vjust` values for `title` and `caption` is not really the best solution for two reasons:

   - if caption has `\n` character, it is formatted very strangely and seems to be dependent on caption length,
   - the title length can change, and therefore the vjust values can change too, so they cannot be constant

Is there any better way to align title and caption to the left side of a plot (so in this case to the left side of a whole picture)?

2. Why does ggplot always sort the data by the alphabetical order of labels? Can somehow the previously done ordering of df be taken into consideration when plotting? Can it be better solved than using `x= reorder(labels, numbers)`?

Comment: Use `hjust = 0` for left justification. They will line up regardless of length, your problem is the `-0.5`.

Comment: As for the ordering, all factors have an implicit order, the default is alphabetical. `ggplot` does not sort, it uses the ordering that is already there, encoded in your factor levels. Indeed, if you want a different order, you must change the order of the factor levels. This can be done many ways, `reorder` is good if you want them ordered by some other variable, directly setting the `levels` is good in most other cases.

Comment: @Gregor Making `vjust=0` is not enough, then they align to the Y-axis. I need a solution for aligning labs to the left side of a whole picture (where "The best brand in the world" starts).

Comment: I would try `cowplot` package then. The ggplot alignments are based on the plotting area. And the way `hjust` works is that 0.5 is the distance needed to change from left justified to center justified - which is dependent on the width of the characters in the string.